# Notation of basis functions for irreducible representations

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, notation, representation-theory, crystals

In character tables for symmetry groups, there are typically basis functions for each irreducible representation given. There are basis functions given like $xy$, $S_x$ or $R$. Could someone explain the notation?
Is $xy$ a synonym for $f(x,y,z)=x\cdot y$?